# Why is the number three block is not aligned to the border like rest of the blocks?(CSS Grid)

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I can only use following properties display, grid-template-columns, grid-template-rows, and grid-column properties to create a grid with 3 columns and 3 rows .

[The Number three block does not go all the way to the border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWLdy.png)

Here's My Code I tried:

Everthing in HTML is contained in a wrapper with class "Container
I'm trying to create a grid layout using the following HTML and CSS code:

**HTML:**

```css
.field-6 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.field-6 .block:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: 1 / 6;
}

.field-6 .block:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.field-6 .block:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 3 / 6;
}

.field-6 .block:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.field-6 .block:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: 2 / 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="field-6">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Thank YOu!

I tried to play with the grid-row and grid-column to get it to the border but does not seem to work.

Comment: You only have 3 columns. Why do you mention 6?

Comment: I tried your code, and it seems to be fine. The only change I made is to give `.field-6`, `width: 100vw; height: 100vh;`